# datatemplate binding image brush source

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, datatemplate

i am binding imagebrush source to my datatemplate in xaml.
the datatemplate is--->

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserGridListTemplate">
            <Grid Height="140" Width="155">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding imagePath}"/>
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

and xaml--->

```
<ListBoxItem ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserGridListTemplate}" >
      <local:MultiLineItem  ImagePath="/ShareItMobileApp;component/Images/facebook-avatar(1).png"/>
</ListBoxItem>
```

but an exception occuring
**AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE [Line: 3 Position: 33]**

can anyone help me about this ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because `ImageBrush` does not derive from `FrameworkElement` which means you can't bind the data directly like that. You can create a converter that will convert your `imagePath` into an ImageBrush and set that ImageBrush as a background to the grid's `Background` property.

First you need to create a converter to convert your path string into an ImageBrush.

```
public class ImagePathConverter : IValueConverter
{     
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter)
    {
        if(value == null) return null;

        Uri uri = new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
        ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        return ib;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can then use that converter on your Grid's background binding (after you've added it as a resource with the key `ImgPathConverter`).

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserGridListTemplate">
   <Grid Height="140" Width="155"
     Background={Binding imagePath, Converter={StaticResource ImgPathConverter}}/>
</DataTemplate>
```